# typescript -- how can I dynamically set tsconfig files?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp, tsconfig

thanks for reading,

I have a typescript setup with gulp currently with tsconfig as follows:

```
{
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "src/app/index.config.ts",
    "src/app/index.constants.ts",
    "src/app/common/settings.controller.ts"
    ....
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "experimentalDecorators" : true,
    "diagnostics" : true,
    "rootDir" : "src/app",
    "outDir": ".tmp/serve/app",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

This is working, except everytime I create another ts file, say src/app/common/login.controller.ts, I would have to add this in the "files":[] array above.

Is there a way I can do this dynamically so that I dont have to constantly update the "files" array?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use globs for the dynamic files? E.g. `"files": [ "typings/index.d.ts", "src/app/**/*.ts" ], ...`

Comment: I tried that. glob doesnt seem to work. It'll say 'File 'src/app/**/*.ts' not found.'

Comment: You don't need the `files` part at all as you are using `rootDir`, I also use it and I have no `files`, and every file I add is automatically compiled (as long as it's somewhere under the `rootDir`)

Comment: If I remove the 'files' entirely, what do I do with the "typings/index.d.ts"? I get a huge error list of ---node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.d.ts(4874,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'xxx' whether I put the typings folder in src/app or not

Comment: How about having a `/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />` in one of the files? Not sure if it will solve it, but worth a check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use globs for dynamic files as Nikos mentioned like:

```
{
    "files": [ "src/app/**/*.ts" ]
}
```

Keep in mind the feature was [merged about a week ago](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8841) and as of writing this it's still only on the master branch so that's probably why you're getting the "not found" error.

You can also try [typescript-with-globs](https://github.com/alexandrudima/typescript-with-globs) to get virtually the same functionality if you rather wait for TS to make a release version with the feature.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, My final solution was to update my tsc compiler from 1.7.5 to 1.8.1 and then to change my tsconfig to use "include": ["src/app/**/*.ts"] with "files": ["typings/index.d.ts"].